# Search an item on AngularFireList

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing an app with Angular + Firebase, and I'm stuck on **how to get an item** and **how to look for it by a certain attribute**.

What is the best way yo do?

Image Table Firebase

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `equalTo` method, as explained in the angularfire2 documentation: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Comment: Thank for your comment, @RenaudTarnec, but look that..
I put the following code on my component:

`this.prestamoService.obtenerPrestamo("P34520181127")
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(item => {
        this.prestamoLista = [];
        item.forEach(element =>{
          let x = element.payload.toJSON();
          x["$key"]  = element.key;
          this.prestamoLista.push(x as Prestamo);
        });
      }); `

And the following method on the service: